# Destructuring with spread syntax in reduce method using typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

This is my example and it works using an alias. example below: 'aliasCatch'

## Passes typescript validation

```js
export type TProcessResponseFunc = (error: TError, stdout: TSTDOut, stderr: TSTDOut) => void;

export interface IObjCMD {
  msg?: string;
  cmd?: string;
  func?: (fn: TProcessResponseFunc) => void;
  catch?: IObjCMD[];
}

const shallowCloneArrObjCMD = (arrNext: IObjCMD[]) => 
  arrNext.reduce((accum, current) => {
    let objCMD: IObjCMD = current;
    if (current.catch) {
      const { ...rest, catch: aliasCatch} = current;
      const arrCatch: IObjCMD[] = aliasCatch ? shallowCloneArrObjCMD(aliasCatch) : [];
      objCMD = { ...rest, catch: arrCatch};
    }
    accum.push({ ...objCMD });
    return accum;
  }, [] as IObjCMD[]);
```

If I replace the alias to access the destructured item directly - ie catch, in example below, then I get errors all over the place:

## Fails typescript validation

```js
const shallowCloneArrObjCMD = (arrNext: IObjCMD[]) => 
  arrNext.reduce((accum, current) => {
    let objCMD: IObjCMD = current;
    if (current.catch) {
      const { ...rest, catch } = current;
      const arrCatch: IObjCMD[] = catch ? shallowCloneArrObjCMD(catch) : [];
      objCMD = { ...rest, catch};
    }
    accum.push({ ...objCMD });
    return accum;
  }, [] as IObjCMD[]);
```

> const { ...rest, catch } = current; - gives me error on the end curly brace: expected : and this breaks the rest of the code.

The only thing I can think what is causing this is because my variable 'catch' might be undefined, as declared in my interface. So making it an alias is bypassing the immediate need for the variable to have value by assigning it to a variable/aka alias.

Some clarification on this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: `catch` is a reserve keyword that is used with try/catch on with promises. You can't use any reserved keyword as indepent variable, just imagine using a variable called `if`, `else`, `for`, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`catch` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). You can't use it as a variable name. `current.catch` is fine, but `const { ...rest, catch } = current` isn't.

I recommend avoiding `catch` (and other reserved words like `delete` or `class`) as a property name altogether. If you can't, you may need to use comments to tell your linter not to insist on destructuring:

```
/* eslint-disable prefer-destructuring */
const arrCatch: IObjCMD[] = current.catch
  ? shallowCloneArrObjCMD(current.catch)
  : [];
objCMD = { ...current };
```

Comment: ahhh - well spotted. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with keywords as property names - `.delete()` and `.catch()` are used all the time - but yes, one has to alias them when declaring variables.